# How can I split content of a file to two different files using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to split a file into two parts

I want to split a single file into two different files using shell script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use linux `split` command, either by lines `split -l<num_of_line> <file_name>` or by size `split -b<size><K|M|G> <file_name>`.

For example: `split -l100 a.txt` will split each 100 lines into separate files.

Here is a [link](https://www.networkworld.com/article/3489256/breaking-linux-files-into-pieces-with-the-split-command.html#:%7E:text=To%20split%20a%20file%20into,simply%20use%20the%20split%20command.&text=By%20default%2C%20the%20split%20command,chunks%20named%20xza%20and%20xzz.) you can see more examples and all details.